# How to configure Azure AD Domain Services to use virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-network, vnet

So, here is my problem.

I'm configuring Azure AD DS and as I see it, you cannot configure it through the new Azure portal (if you can, kindly direct me to that resource).

I've Azure virtual machines created and attached to a virtual network. All the VMs and virtual network are created using new portal. So, when I go ahead and configure Azure AD DS by going into classic portal > directory > configure and try to select the virtual network, it doesn't appear (since Vnet was created in the new portal).

What's the solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All the VMs and virtual network are created using new portal.

For now, Azure AD Domain Services **cannot be enabled in virtual networks created using Azure Resource Manager.**

In your scenario, I think we should use **VNet peering** or **site-to-site VPN** to connect classic Vnet and ARM vnet. You can connect a Resource Manager-based virtual network to the Azure classic virtual network in which you have enabled Azure AD Domain Services. This connection enables you to use the managed domain with your workloads deployed in the Resource Manager-based virtual network.

[image]

More information about select a virtual network for AD DS, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-networking).

Comment: All right. I was able to create a VNet peering between ARM vnet and classic vnet. I updated DNS setting in classic vnet. Now, I'm trying to join this domain but it is still unable to find it.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. Your solution has worked. 

I had to restart the DNS Client from services and client VM. Thanks.